# Touchpad not working Toshiba A660-167 (Ubuntu 64bit)

Tags: touchpad

I have a Toshiba Satellite A660-167 I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) but the Touchpad is not working. It works in Windows 7 (I have a dual boot) but not in Ubuntu. I use a USB mouse and it works fine but not the touchpad. Are there any extra drivers for my Touchpad?? Any idea how to make it work??? Can anyone help?????

Comment: Have you got the synaptiks touchpad drivers?? Or have you tried toggling the on/off state of the touchpad?

Comment: I tried the on/off button but does not work. It does work however the left/right click button of the touchpad. There is no problem with the touchpad when boot to windows 7 (Have dual boot). As for synaptic touchpad driver that applies only for windows operating systems. My problem is with my Ubuntu!